# An anime about MMO with a glasses wearing protagonist

Tags: log-horizon

A friend of mine recently recommended me an anime. He told me the name, but I forgot to note it down, and now I don't remember it.

It's about people who are trapped in a fictional MMO and can't get back to the real world. When he told me that, I asked if he was talking about *Sword Arts Online*, but he told me that wasn't it. Unlike SAO, people who die in that MMO revive some time later, so death is not permanent.

He said I'd be particularly interested in the protagonist, since he's smart, analytical, quite the strategist, and wears glasses.

He also told me the anime was more about society than about the actual game.

Finally, I remember him telling me that the anime is still ongoing, but that was a few weeks ago, so it might have ended recently, or not.

What's the name of the anime he told me about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do believe you're talking about [**Log Horizon**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_Horizon). Some relevant plot points that matches your description:

- The setting is an MMO world called *Elder Tales*. All the players currently logged on cannot log out.
- The main character wears glasses, is smart, and is considered one of
  the best strategists in the game's community.
- There is no perma-death, but there is a penalty for it, which will be
  revealed later in the series.
- The first season has heavy emphasis on the politics and economy of
  the game world. It shows how the players and the NPC interacts, how the NPC interacts with other NPCs, etc.

For more info, you can check out its [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_Horizon) or look through its own [Wikia site](http://log-horizon.wikia.com/wiki/Log_Horizon_Wiki).

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly the name he told me; now I remember :)

Comment: Haha, just the title was enough to recognize this one for anybody who saw it xD